# POJO from JSON through Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

How I can convert it to POJO? I have a little troubles with "langs": {}. Is the Langs a Java object with a random quantity of variables?

Need for GsonFactory / Retrofit 2. Regards.

```
{
    "dirs": [
        "ru-en",
        "ru-pl",
        "ru-hu",
      ...
    ],
   "langs": {
        "ru": "russian",
        "en": "english",
        "pl": "polish",
     ...
   }

}
```

Comment: @Japu_D_Cret no, langs is like Java object with random quantity of variables: ru, en, etc.

Comment: so a simple Map - and now?

Comment: @A.Alex It is a duplicate. If you'd read the linked question best answer, you'd see the following: _Google Gson supports generics and nested beans. The [] in JSON represents an array and should map to a Java collection such as List or just a plain Java array. The {} in JSON represents an object and should map to a Java Map or just some JavaBean class._ -- exactly your case.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv simple Map is null after GsonConverterFactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Example {

    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("dirs")
    public List<String> dirs;

    @NonNull
    @SerializedName("langs")
    public Map<String, String> langs;

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Langs is null after GsonFactory.

Comment: @A.Alex If I'd post an answer to the question, I'd answer exactly how [shmakova](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4141049/shmakova) did: this is a correct POJO mapping. If you get `null`s for any reason -- then you can have two options here: 1) either you're trying to deserialize a JSON document that does not match the one you've posted in your question; 2) or your `Gson` instance used in Retrofit is corrupted. I don't believe the latter.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Thank you for help. I found the problem. Server didn't send "langs" without special parameter.

Comment: @A.Alex No problem. Please accept the answer since it helped you. Thanks.